# Excel: Continue Sequence with text and numbers

Tags: excel, sequence

I have a sequence in excel:

- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_001
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_001
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_001
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_002
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_002
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_002
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_003
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_003
- TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_003

When I try to Auto Fill the sequence by selecting all of the above values and dragging the little box at the bottom right of the selected cells downwards, it starts with ...001 again instead of continuing with ...004. How do I make the sequence continue indefinitely?

Comment: Is VBA a possible solution?

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: If you simply begin with `TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_001` and drag it down then it will work. Then all you need to do is : `a. Paste the generated data twice` and then `b. Apply sort` to regroup.

Comment: @Andreas I have no experience with VBA whatsoever but if there is a solution that way, then that's fine.

Comment: @JvdV I am using Excel Version 2012(Build 13530.20376 Click-to-Run)

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij That's actually a nice idea. I will use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this thread is finished for me, I am just copying @shrivallabha.redij 's comment here.

If you simply begin with TEXT1-TEXT2-TEXT3_001 and drag it down then it will work. Then all you need to do is : a. Paste the generated data twice and then b. Apply sort to regroup.